# PhantomJS rasterize to PNG OK but fails for PDF

Tags: pdf, phantomjs

My goal is to get a vector graphic of a web page and insert it into a PDF report that I am generating.

Currently I have some code that uses PhantomJS (1.9.8) to capture a screen shot of the required browser page as a PNG.  In case it helps the page is of a single chart rendered by AMCharts

> phantomjs.exe .\examples\rasterize.js http://some.URL test.png

My code reads the generated file and inserts the PNG into the PDF report and all is good.

I am now trying to improve this and insert a vector graphic into the PDF report.  Idea was to generate a PDF using PhantomJS and grab the graphic out of it and insert it into my PDF report.

> phantomjs.exe .\examples\rasterize.js http://the.same.URL test.pdf

But now all I get is a blank PDF document.  It's a valid PDF but there is nothing in it!

If I change the URL to one of the AMChart examples everything appears to be fine.  So it's something to do with my actual web page but what?

I have had a read around and the only thing I have tried is to remove all the @media tags as I understand that PhantomJS will try to use the @media print style.  This did not help me.

I'm stuck!  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide your js so we can try to replicate the problem

Comment: I'm using the default rasterize.js that comes with the examples.  Only difference is I have upped the timeout a bit.